# Dynamically creating and naming arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I may be looking at this one the wrong way. I think that dynamically naming the object is the difficult part rather than creating it.

Basically I have an array of arrays and I want to get the nested arrays out.

```
var $jTableTRS = $('tr.child');
var $jTableTRSArr = jQuery.makeArray($jTableTRS);
```

each slot in $jTableTRSArr has an array object contained. Thing is i will never know how many arrays are in the $jTableTRSArr.

```
for(var i=0;i<$jTableTRSArr.length;i++)
    {
            //var  tempArray(withuniqueidentifier) = $jTableTRSArr[i]
    }
```

This means I could reference each nested array by its name like

```
tempArray1[0].variable
and not $jTableTRSArr[0].variable.
```

I'm essentially bringing the nested arrays up one level.

Can this be done or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you say you will not know how many arrays are into $jTableTRSArr how would you know which intex to use in your variable? And what is wrong using $jTableTRSArr.length to know how many arrays are there?

Comment: I mean I will never know before the for loop. Basically Its a table with editable columns. Each nested array is a row. I will know how many default elements there are but not any extras they added on. And i don't know what index they will use, I will have to use something like i to name them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create dynamic variable names, you could do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    window['MyNewArray-' + i] = arr[i];
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?